# Extracting levels of a factor from column number-R

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` (`df`) with column name `v1` which is a `factor`. Like:

```
df
# v1
# --
# a
# b
# c
```

When I want to get levels of the `factor` I get:

By column name:

```
levels(df$v1)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

By column number:

```
levels(df[1])
# NULL
```

Why do I get `NULL` when I use column number.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: levels(df[[1]]) should work. df[1] extracts a list with one element df[[1]] extracts the contents

Comment: Why is that? df is not defined as a list. It is defined as data frame in my example.

Comment: data.frames are also/primarily lists. try `is.list(iris)` ;-)

Comment: Or try `df[,1]`. This means selecting all rows and the first column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the idea. Thanks again for sharing your time.

Comment: Always useful to have a gander at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico. Recommended topic is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  levels(df[,1]) 
  [1] "a" "b" "c"
```